# How to validate a form if multiple elements uses the same custom validation directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I've wrote a validation directive for dates in this format `MM/YYYY` that works nice if I have only one element to validate per page, but when I have more than one element I notice the validation is mixed, so is probably a `scope` misunderstanding.

I mean i get e validation error of `minDate` for `form.startDate` element instead of seeing it only for `form.endDate`.

this is my view:

```
<form>
    <input id="start-date"
           type="text"
           validate-short-date
           data-max-date="{{endingDate | toDate:'MM/YYYY':'YYYYMM'}}"
           data-greater-date="{{nextMonth | toDate:'MM/YYYY':'YYYYMM'}}"
           name="startDate"
           data-ng-model="startingDate">

    <input id="end-date"
           type="text"
           validate-short-date
           data-min-date="{{thisMonth | toDate:'MM/YYYY':'YYYYMM'}}"
           name="endDate"
           data-ng-model="endingDate">
</form>
```

I thought to use `scope[ngModel.$name]` but the problem is fixed only partially, so I probably missing how should I use the scope to keep directive divided.

this is the directive:

```
.directive('validateShortDate', ['moment', function(moment) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            var pattern, regex;
            pattern = '^((0[0-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$';
            regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

            var isEmpty = function(modelValue){
                return modelValue === '' || modelValue === null || angular.isUndefined(modelValue);
            };

            var toDate = function(modelValue){
                return moment(modelValue, 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYYMM');
            };

            scope[ngModel.$name] = {};
            scope[ngModel.$name].maxDate = false;
            scope[ngModel.$name].minDate = false;
            scope[ngModel.$name].greaterDate = false;
            scope[ngModel.$name].lesserDate = false;

            attr.$observe('maxDate', function() {
                if (!isEmpty(attr.maxDate)) {
                    scope[ngModel.$name].maxDate = attr.maxDate;
                    ngModel.$validate();
                }
            });

            attr.$observe('greaterDate', function() {
                if (!isEmpty(attr.greaterDate)) {
                    scope[ngModel.$name].greaterDate = attr.greaterDate;
                    ngModel.$validate();
                }
            });

            attr.$observe('minDate', function() {
                if (!isEmpty(attr.minDate)) {
                    scope[ngModel.$name].minDate = attr.minDate;
                    ngModel.$validate();
                }
            });

            attr.$observe('lesserDate', function() {
                if (!isEmpty(attr.lesserDate)) {
                    scope[ngModel.$name].lesserDate = attr.lesserDate   ;
                    ngModel.$validate();
                }
            });

            ngModel.$validators.maxDate = function(modelValue) {
                console.log(ngModel.$name);
                var maxDate = scope[ngModel.$name].maxDate;
                if (!isEmpty(modelValue) && !isEmpty(maxDate) && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                    return toDate(modelValue) <= maxDate;
                }
                return true;
            };

            ngModel.$validators.greaterDate = function(modelValue) {
                var greaterDate = scope[ngModel.$name].greaterDate;
                if (!isEmpty(modelValue) && !isEmpty(greaterDate) && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                    return toDate(modelValue) < greaterDate;
                }
                return true;
            };

            ngModel.$validators.minDate = function(modelValue) {
                var minDate = scope[ngModel.$name].minDate || false;
                if (!isEmpty(modelValue) && !isEmpty(minDate) && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                    return toDate(modelValue) >= minDate;
                }
                return true;
            };

            ngModel.$validators.lesserDate = function(modelValue) {
                var lesserDate = scope[ngModel.$name].lesserDate;
                if (!isEmpty(modelValue) && !isEmpty(lesserDate) && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                    return toDate(modelValue) > lesserDate;
                }
                return true;
            };

            ngModel.$validators.valid = function(modelValue) {
                return isEmpty(modelValue) || regex.test(modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

How can I keep more validation directives in the same view?

Comment: Hey, have you made any progress on this? Was my suggestion able to help you at all?..???..

Comment: Still wondering if this is an issue or my suggestion was able to help you. Please respond

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions are correct, this is a scoping issue. You are wanting to have an isolate scope on these directives. Check out [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) for a nice breakdown on this topic. Regarding your code, try this following change...

```
.directive('validateShortDate', ['moment', function(moment) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {}, // -- isolate - not shared with parent scope
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        [...]
```

Furthermore, if you want those attributes as named scope properties, the article also covers techniques to do so. This should alleviate you of your current work-around of `scope[ngModel.$name]` to just `scope.name` within your directive. This would be seen as such...

```
scope: {
    'name': '='
    [...] // -- other attributes to be named on scope
}
```

Also explore the usage in the blog covering how to pass `{{ interpolated }}` values with the `@` character vs. `=` on your scope. Simply...

> - @  Used to pass a string value into the directive
> - =    Used to create a two-way binding to an object that is passed into the directive
> - &    Allows an external function to be passed into the directive and invoked